# how to provide space between boxes in given code for different size devices like given image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ21h.png)?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Assignment solution module-2</title>
<style>

    /********** Base styles **********/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 35px;  
  text-align: center;    
}

    section{
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color: darkblue;
        float:right;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size:25px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;

    }  

.styleText {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom:15px; 
  padding-left:15px;    
  background-color:gray;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;    
}
    p{
        margin-top: 25px;
    }


/* Simple Responsive Framework. */
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

    /********** Large devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

    /********** Medium devices only **********/

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Our Menu</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="styleText col-lg-4 col-md-6"><section>Chicken</section><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae efficitur ante. Praesent erat quam, pharetra ut posuere nec, bibendum tempor quam. Phasellus feugiat ligula ipsum, quis sollicitudin urna finibus in. Fusce sit amet nunc interdum nulla bibendum molestie ut non mi. Nulla in euismod purus, in dictum urna</p></div>
  <div class="styleText col-lg-4 col-md-6"><section>Beef</section><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae efficitur ante. Praesent erat quam, pharetra ut posuere nec, bibendum tempor quam. Phasellus feugiat ligula ipsum, quis sollicitudin urna finibus in. Fusce sit amet nunc interdum nulla bibendum molestie ut non mi. Nulla in euismod purus, in dictum urna</p></div>
  <div class="styleText col-lg-4 col-md-12"><section>Shushi</section><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vitae efficitur ante. Praesent erat quam, pharetra ut posuere nec, bibendum tempor quam. Phasellus feugiat ligula ipsum, quis sollicitudin urna finibus in. Fusce sit amet nunc interdum nulla bibendum molestie ut non mi. Nulla in euismod purus, in dictum urna</p></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[ The below image depicts the design of page needed when used in large devices(pixels>1200).
and the spaces between each box is missing in code I have written and that is the problem I am seeking answer. please feel free to provide suggestions]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ21h.png)

the above code does not use any framework and only uses media queries that makes responsive page base on 12-grid system.

Comment: Try adding `margin:5px;` after your `border: 1px solid green;`

Comment: RobJarvis ..actually I can't do that because adding margins even upto 1px disturbs the orientation of program . i.e. boxes are not oriented in way needed like image provided above.

Comment: If you will also subtract from the width on your `.col-lg-4` class under your Large devices media query, you can even out the spacing and keep the same layout. For example, try adding `margin-right: 1%` and change `.col-lg-4` from `width: 33.33%` to `width:32.33%`.

Comment: Thanks Rob....this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Changing my comment to an answer, since OP says this fixed the problem:

If you will also subtract from the width on your `.col-lg-4` class under your Large devices media query, you can even out the spacing and keep the same layout.

For example, try adding `margin-right: 1%` and change `.col-lg-4` from `width: 33.33%` to `width:32.33%`